# Linear Independence/Dependence Contradiction

Tags: proof-verification, independence

> I am trying to determine if $u_1(x)=x^3, \ u_2(x)=|x|^3$ is linearly independent/dependent on $\mathbb{R}$.

I first computed the Wronskian using two cases.

Case $1$ $(x\geq 0)$: $$W(x)=\begin{vmatrix}
x^3 & x^3 \\ 
3x^2 & 3x^2 \\ 
 \notag
\end{vmatrix}=0$$
Case $2$ $(x< 0)$: $$W(x)=\begin{vmatrix}
x^3 & -x^3 \\ 
3x^2 & -3x^2 \\ 
 \notag
\end{vmatrix}=0$$

I then used the definition of linear independence $(c_1,c_2\in\mathbb{R})$:
$$(x\ge 0): \ \ c_1x^3+c_2x^3=0 \ \ \ \ \ (1) \\ (x<0): \ \ c_1x^3-c_2x^3=0 \ \ \ \ \ (2)$$
$$(1)+(2)=2c_1x^3=0\implies c_1=0 \\ \therefore c_2x^3=0\implies c_2=0$$
So since $c_1=c_2=0$, both functions should be linearly independent.

What I don't understand is why can both functions be linearly constucted from the other, doesn't this show **linear dependence**?

e.g. if $$x<0\implies |x|^3=-x^3 \\ \therefore -u_1(x)=u_2(x)$$
e.g. $$u_1(x)=\sin(2x), \ u_2(x)=\sin(x)\cos(x)$$ are linearly dependent as they can be written as a linear combination of each other.
Linearly independent functions can not be written as a linear combination of said functions.

Comment: I can construct $\sin$ using $\cos$, by the formula $\cos(\pi/2 - x)=\sin(x)$. However as you stated, it does not mean that $\cos$ and $\sin$ are linearly dependant, quite the contrary. Actually, the term *linear* really is important. It is not just any kind of dependancy, it is a very specific one.

Comment: That may have been a bad example. I shall re-edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Theorem about Wronskian and linear independent is a statement about functions which are solutions to linear differential equations not arbitrary functions such as $x^3$ and $|x|^3$

What you have discovered is that these two functions are not solutions to a lineare differential equation on the whole real line.

Comment: I understand that the linear Independence/dependence of said arbitrary functions cannot be determined by their Wronskian alone, that is why I have resorted to the definition of linear independence. My question is, why does the formal definition confirm linear independence, but then in the case when, for example, $x<0$, does $-u_1=u_2$, as I mentioned. If they were linearly independent, this should not be possible, right?

Comment: Your functions are linearly dependent on $R^{>0}$ and on $R ^{<0}$ but they are not linearly dependent on $R$

Comment: I see. Is this why we must test this using the definition of linear independence, as this considers the whole real line? My example that I mentioned $(-u_1=u_2)$ only takes into account $\mathbb{R^{<0}}$

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: Just one last question. If the functions are linearly dependent on $\mathbb{R^{>0}}$ and $\mathbb{R^{<0}}$, why are they not linearly dependent on the real line? I've shown they're linearly dependent on both sides of $0$.

Comment: Because the same constant does not work for the whole real line. One is a constant multiple of the other on positive values and  another constant multiple of the other on the negative values. Just as your $x^3$ and$ |x^3|.$

Comment: Is this a necessary condition for linear independence?  I'd like to read about this if you have any links.

Comment: In general two functions  are linearly dependent if one is a constant multiple of the other. Otherwise they are linearly independent. For example $\sin 2x$ and $\sin x \cos x$ are dependent because we have the formula $ \sin 2x=2\sin x \cos x$

Comment: I see. So $u_1, \ u_2$ are not linearly dependent as $c_1u_1\neq c_2u_2 \ \ \forall c_1,c_2\in\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: That is correct.